# Accessing the users music library from within an ap

Tags: iphone

What is the best way to allow the user to access their music library and play their own music within an app?

Does it call the library and when the user is done it dismissing the window and returns to the running app or how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only access the music library using the MediaPlayer framework. Check out the [iPod Library Access Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008765) and the related Apple sample code project, [AddMusic](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AddMusic/Introduction/Intro.html).